# How to use CPU/RAM of a distant (Internet-connected) computer to run a local program?

Tags: networking, internet

There are two computers pc1 and pc2. I want to run one program on pc1 but I want to use pc2 resources such as RAM and cpu to run and compute the calculations.

Is it possible to run a program on pc1 and use pc2 to do the computations? The only way that I can connect the two computer is via Internet.

Comment: Welcome on Software Recommendation. Can you add more details about your requirement? What kind of calculation you want to share (game, scientific, ...)? Is it for a specific program? What is your OS? ... I suggest you to read [this meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) post about question requirements.

Comment: yashar, this site is about *software recommendations* – not about solving any computer problem. Your question might, however, fit on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I suspect there's already a question on this on SU. Might have been closed though.

Comment: @ Fractaliste. My OS is windows 7 on both systems.
I want to run a scientific software on pc1 and use pc2 to do calculations. pc1 is used by another user, and I use pc2 for my personal tasks too. So, while it is computing for pc1, I will be using it for my own tasks.

Comment: If you want to use the resources of pc2, then the program has to run on pc2. You can install the program on pc2 and [control it from pc1](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/is-there-a-program-to-control-other-computers-from-another-computer).